# 2-REA PA degrees

Tags: lo.logic, computability-theory, recursively-enumerable, recursive-enumerability-above

Remember that an n-REA set is a set of the form $A_0 \oplus A_1 \oplus \cdots \oplus A_n$ with $A_n$ relatively r.e. in $A_m, m<n$ (so $A_0$ is r.e.) and that a degree is PA just if it computes a path through every infinite computable tree.

By Arslanov's completeness criterion no incomplete r.e. set can be of PA degree.  While pursuing another problem I'm pretty sure I constructed a low 2-REA set of PA degree but before I bother to include that writeup in some paper (it's not the most riveting proof but seems worth mentioning somewhere) or even spend a bunch of time double checking it I wanted to see if it's known.

So anyone know if this result (or refutation) is already in the literature or is trivial to derive from it (e.g., clever use of relativized jump inversion)?

Comment: Maybe I'm confused by the definition, but how is an $n$-REA degree different from $\Sigma_{n+1}$? There are low $\Delta_2$ PA-degrees, FWIW.

Comment: Because you have to build it up in pieces and keep them all (A1 on its own is Sigma2 but it's not 2-REA ..A0+A1 is).  For instance, you can have a non-computable Sigma n set that doesn't compute any r.e set.  The same isn't true of an n-REA set because first non-computable Ai is r.e..  Practically speaking, in this case the problem is you have this r.e part of set and u can't unenumerate elements when you might like to for lowness.

Comment: You can sorta think of n-REA sets as Sigma n sets that carry along their construction via repeated Sigma 1 definitions but carrying around the sets used to build it makes it much harder to build sets that have limited computational power.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, I think your theorem is false. Call a set A low-for-PA if for every PA degree P, A+P is PA relative to A. It follows from Corollary 2.3 of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1207.2533.pdf) by Reimann and Day that every low r.e. set is low-for-PA (I also know of another more direct proof of this fact). Suppose A_0 is r.e., A_1 is r.e. relative to A_0, A_0+A_1 is low and A_0+A_1 is PA. Since A_0 is low-for-PA, A_0+A_1 is PA relative to A_0. But by Arslanov's completeness criterion, this means that A_0+A_1 is Turing equivalent to the jump of A_0 and hence not low.

Comment: Continuing what Patrick wrote, no n-REA set is of low PA degree.  In contrast, the construction of the low basis theorem produces a set of $\omega$-REA degree.

Comment: Hmm, that looks like a counterexample alright.  Not too surprised as I haven't put in the detailed effort to double check my reasoning.  Thanks greatly .. for some reason I'm not seeing comment upvotes.

Comment: Dan, yes I see (well already knew...nicely bounded number of mind changes) the w-REA point but are you assuming or know that collarly 2.3 relativizes and are arguing by induction to reach the conclusion for n-REA?

Comment: @PeterGerdes The fact that a low r.e. set is low-for-PA does relativize and so you can continue the argument I gave by induction. The alternate argument I know of that low r.e. sets are low-for-PA is not the same as what Dan mentioned though (it involves reasoning in the nonstandard model of PA coded by the PA degree and actually shows that if A is r.e. and P is PA then either A + P is PA relative to A or A + P computes 0').

Comment: I agree that low r.e. is low-for-PA, but I don't see why it follows from 2.3 in the linked paper?

Comment: Ohh that's good thx!  I'm curious how being r.e. helps in that computable homeomorphism question.

Comment: Sorry, I deleted my earlier comment about homeomorphic $\Pi^0_1$ classes because I'm suddenly doubting it.

Comment: @DanTuretsky Corollary 2.3 of that paper says that if A is r.e. and P is PA such that P computes A then either P computes 0' or P is PA relative to A. If A is low then both of these conclusions imply P is PA relative to A.

Comment: Edit: Nevermind, I see.  We're considering P+A, not P.

Comment: The argument I know of goes like this though: if P is PA then P codes the first order theory of some model M of PA. There are two cases: either there is a nonstandard element n of M such that the enumeration of A below n is correct or for every nonstandard element n of M, there is some element of the complement of A that M believes is enumerated into A below n. In the former case, A is in the standard system of M so P is PA relative to A. And in the latter case, A + P can compute 0'.

Comment: Also I'm having trouble with the proof of 2.3 in the linked paper as they say it only uses two facts but then there is this Q whose existence I'm not seeing a justification for.  Am I being dumb?

Comment: @PeterGerdes If T is a computable infinite binary tree and M is a nonstandard model of PA then there is a path through T which is in the standard system of M. The elementary diagram of M is PA over everything in the standard system of M.

Comment: The set of (X,Y) such that X is a completion of PA and Y is a completion of $PA^X$ is a $\Pi^0_1$-class.  $P$ computes some element (Q, S), and as it computes $S$, $P$ is PA over $Q$.

Comment: @PatrickLutz How does the elementary diagram help here?  Isn't that something which computes 0^n for all n?  I presume this is explaining connection between being contained in the standard initial segment (or does std system mean something different?)

Comment: @PeterGerdes the elementary diagram of the true natural numbers is Turing equivalent to $0^{(\omega)}$ but every PA degree computes the elementary diagram of *some* model of PA.

Comment: The standard system of a model M of PA is the set of subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ which are equal to $x \cap \mathbb{N}$ for some $M$-finite set $x$.

Comment: @DanTuretsky I'm surely just being dumb now but what is S in your argument.  We want Q so P is PA over Q but your arg only helps if there infinite path with second component P which is just another way of saying there is some Q of PA degree which P is PA over.

Comment: @PeterGerdes Not sure if this was clear: my first comment talking about nonstandard models of PA was sketching an argument that low r.e. sets are low-for-PA. My second comment was responding to your question abut the Reimann-Day paper.

Comment: @PeterGerdes In Dan's argument, P computes both Q and S and S is PA over Q so P is also PA over Q.

Comment: ohh duh yah I was misreading thanks.  Re elementary diagram  was a bit confused about how u handle non-std params but I guess we just picking some consistent path and using Henkinization so not a problem.  OK thanks a huge amount that's a neat proof...if you want karma or to close Q feel free to write it up as ans or if not I'll do it in a couple days if still marked open since this is a great ans.  Ill up vote comments once I on computer again not phone.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Theorem 5.1 in [Recursively Enumerable Sets Modulo Iterated Jumps and Extensions of Arslanov's Completeness Criterion](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2274816?seq=1) states that Arslanov's completeness criterion holds for $n$-REA sets. The paper is from 1989 and by Jockusch, Lerman, Soare, and Solovay.

Comment: Thanks for the cute...now to figure out what I fucked up ;-)

Comment: Doh...I let my requirements be pushed down an infinite path on tree so never satisfied...well knowing it was wrong helped